# Problems with installation on Xubuntu 11.10 LibreOffice

Tags: 11.10, libreoffice, xubuntu

Good afternoon, I have a problem when installing Xubuntu LibreOffice in 11.10.

I open the console and add the PPA and all goes well, the problem arises when I give the order to installation.

```
san-san @ Lenovo: ~ $ sudo apt-get install LibreOffice
Reading package lists ... done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... done
Failed to install some packages. This may mean that
you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the distribution
unstable, that some required packages have not been created or
been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  LibreOffice: Depends: LibreOffice-core (= 1:3.4.4 ~ rc1-0ubuntu1 ~ ppa1) but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-writer but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-calc but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-impress but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-draw but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-math but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-base but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-report-builder-bin but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-filter-mobiledev but it will not install
            Depends on: LibreOffice-java-common (> = 1:3.4.4 ~ rc1 ~) but it will not install
E: Could not fix the problems, he has held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What PPA, and why? Libre Office is in the repositories, so that you didn't have to add anything. All you had to do was search for the `libreoffice` in Synaptic and install it. Xubuntu uses the same repositories as the rest of the *buntu family.

Comment: When installing LibreOffice That hay Integration Options: Gnome, kde, gtk +, which I select?

Comment: Xubuntu uses gtk, so either that or Gnome should be ok. Don't forget to remove the PPA first.